# How to start a output restricted double ended queue in Java?

Tags: java, queue, double

I was trying to figure out how to start writing a double ended queue with restricted output using Java, so I can input elements from both ends but remove them from just one.
I have done single queues, and this is my first time doing a dequeue and the book I'm reading doesn't help much.

I'm just a little lost and double seems more complicated than single.

**EDIT**

Single Queue Code:

```
public class ListQueue<AnyType> implements Queue<AnyType>
{
    private ListNode<AnyType> front;
    private ListNode<AnyType> back;
    private int counter;

    public ListQueue( )
    {
        front = back = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return front == null;
    }

    public void enqueue( AnyType x )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )    // Make queue of one element
            back = front = new ListNode<AnyType>( x );
        else                // Regular case
            back = back.next = new ListNode<AnyType>( x );
        counter++;
    }

    public AnyType dequeue( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new UnderflowException( "ListQueue dequeue" );

        AnyType returnValue = front.element;
        front = front.next;
        counter--;
        return returnValue;
    }

    public AnyType getFront( ) 
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            throw new UnderflowException( "ListQueue getFront" );
        return front.element;
    }

    public void makeEmpty( )
    {
        front = null;
        back = null;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

There it is

**EDIT**

Here is the `ListNode` class

```
class ListNode<AnyType>
{

    public ListNode( AnyType theElement )
    {
        this( theElement, null );
    }

    public ListNode( AnyType theElement, ListNode<AnyType> n )
    {
        element = theElement;
        next    = n;
    }

    public AnyType   element;
    public ListNode<AnyType> next;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Can you use existing Java types like `Deque`?

Comment: from the OP it sounds like the goal is to wrote a custom data structure -- " I have done single queues"

Comment: Well, it is HW but it's not necessary to do a Dequeue, I'm just adding a little challenge to it

Answer (score 1):

With a double-ended queue, you keep two references, one to the next element and one to the previous element.

Start from the single-ended queue and add the backwards references.

Comment: so I'd have 4 references? That's what I don't get

Comment: each node has two references, one to the previous and one to the next.  where as the singly-linked list has N links, the doubly linked list has 2N links

Comment: How do I do that?
This is what I have: private ListNode<AnyType> front; 
    private ListNode<AnyType> back;

Comment: Do you have an implementation of ListNode?

Comment: You need to add a field "prev" to ListNode

Comment: What do you mean an implementation of ListNode? The ListNode class?

Comment: add a field "prev" to the listnode.  Then, in the enqueue and dequeue methods, make sure that the next and prev nodes are properly updated

Comment: public ListNode<AnyType> prev; ??

Comment: But isn't that why the Nodes front and back are for? Why do I need a prev? Don't I need like, I don't know. I'm lost. :S